# CRM 2011 IFD deployment http 404

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

I've installed a new instance of CRM2011 following this guide (with IFD ) http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/server-tips/microsoft-crm-2011-how-to-configure-ifd-hosted-setup/ . Unfortunately after I try to access the website on https:444 it gives me an 404 site / directory not found :) . The site itself it is intact as I can access it via http:5555 (default port for CRM ) .

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

The steps to fix this have been :
-Federation services - I made a binding in IIS with localhost which prevented ADFS service to function properly .
-remade all the authentication chain from ADFS management with *Name for windows .

It all worked out .